# How to migrate Devise Rails Passwords to PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, passwords

We are in the process of moving a website from Ruby to PHP. We already have a users table where the passwords were generated by Devise.

I am trying to find out how Devise stores the password in MySQL. Appears at first look to be a SHA encrypted with a salt, but I am not clear on how the salt is selected.

I am trying to work the Devise code back to pseudo code so that we can the re write the code in PHP. Looking for help or suggestions with this.

Trying to avoid resetting everybody's password, but depending on how well Devise stores passwords that might be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can go export your database and import it to your PHP database?

Answer (score 0):

Devise uses bcrypt you should be asking "How do I use bcrypt with PHP". This question has already been asked:

[PHP and Bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056154/php-and-bcrypt)

[Ruby bcrypt password retrieval in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321075/ruby-bcrypt-password-retrieval-in-php)

Basycally you should use the [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function with blowfish algorithm.